# Redirect to Controller results 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, laragon

I am creating a web application in Codeignitor using Laragon as my local server.  When I try to "redirect" to a Controller - I get "404 Page Not Found".  If I redirect to View - it works.  I can access Controllers with other methods such as "Form Open".

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is my Controller - for a test I used Redirect to a View "page-login" and a Controller "Private-area". I can access the View, but the Controller sends to 404 Page Not Found.

```
if($this->form_validation->run()){
    $result = $this->login_model->can_login($this->input->post('user_email'), $this->input->post('user_password'));
    if($result == ''){
        redirect('private_area');
    }
    else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $result);
        redirect('page-login');
```

FYI I can access Controllers (in this example "Register") using other methods such as Form Open like this:

```
<?php echo form_open('register/validation'); ?>
```

Why do I get the 404 error?

Comment: You are getting mixed up in the idea of routes, controllers, and views.  It will be come clearer if you get that straight.  You don't redirect to controllers, or to views - you redirect to *routes*.  Likewise `form_open()` does not take a controller as a parameter, but a route.  [The intro tutorial](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html), and [the routes documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html), describe it well.

Comment: You mentioned private_area in redirect function while you mentioned controller name Private-area. Both are different. You should redirect to private-area.

Comment: Thanks  @Don'tPanic!  You nailed it.  I think I solved my problem - see my answer below. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect syntax is incorrect:

the [CI function redirect()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=redirect#redirect) is structured like this:

> `redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL)`

keep in mind to use a relative path like '/my_controller/my_function'

as in this example:

> `redirect('/login/form/');`

you need to autoload/load the URL helper with: `$this->load->helper('url');`

the [form_open()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_open#form_open) syntax is correct, you need to autoload/load the Form Helper with: `$this->load->helper('form');`

Answer (score 0):

`redirect()` function

> Does a “header redirect” to the URI specified. If you specify the full site URL that link will be built, but for local links simply providing the URI segments to the controller you want to direct to will create the link. The function will build the URL based on your config file values. (- [source](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect))

So, the url must be

```
redirect("/controller/method/parameters");
```

Or full url

In your code, Codeigniter will look for the `index()` method of `private_area` controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All!

So I think @Don'tPanic nailed it.  I thought "Redirect" would point to a Controller - but it points to a Route.  So I created a Route in my Routes.php file where

```
$route['private_area'] = 'private_area';
```

And everything works.  Is this the correct way to do this?

Ie to define Routes in the Routes.php file...then call upon them as required using "Redirect"?

Comment: you don't need to create a route only for this. `redirect('/private_area')` should work without it too, it points to controller `private_area()` and its function `index()`

Comment: @Vickel but it doesn't.  However when I enter  ```redirect('private_area/index')``` it does work....I dont know why it would need to define the function index() as it should default to that...shouldn't it?

Comment: this depends on your base_url settings, the docs say *redirect() does a “header redirect” to the URI specified. If you specify the full site URL that link will be built, but for local links simply providing the URI segments to the controller you want to direct to will create the link. The function will build the URL based on your config file values.*

Comment: As described in the docs I linked to in my comment, it is a standard MVC pattern to set up routes that map to `/[controller-class]/[controller-method]/[arguments]`.  If you have no routes, CI will try to guess what to do using this pattern.  So strictly speaking if your route segments map exactly to the corresponding controllers and methods, you don't need a route.  But it is not hard to add them, and you end up with a clear, documented understanding of what routes map where - this is much better practice.